# Dbpedia indexing for named entity linking (chatbot)

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, full-text-search, chatbot, dbpedia

I'm working on a project for a chatbot. The chatbot must answer users' questions using dbpedia, and was initially trained with the IBM watson assistant service. However, in this service it is necessary to manually fill in the dictionaries in which the dbpedia entities and their synonyms are defined. The entities defined in the dictionaries are those that are recognized in the user's natural language questions.

For example, in the question "Who is the director of spiderman?" the chatbot recognizes dbo:director and Spiderman entity, because they are defined in the dictionary.

Manually inserting all the dbpedia entities in the dictionaries is limiting and for the moment the chatbot recognizes only the few entities included in the dictionary.

I therefore want to recognize dbpedia entities present in natural language questions written by the user by exploiting an indexing of the dbpedia rdf datasets on something like Elasticsearch or Lucene, and then using the full-text search. I thought of indexing entities using only the literal properties of dbpedia (to use full-text search). Before continuing I would like to know if it is a right approach, and have some advice on how to proceed in setting the indexes and on how to effectively exploit the full-text search.

Thank you

Comment: This is far too broad a question for this site... https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I would suggest you start by looking into [existing DBpedia-related projects](https://wiki.dbpedia.org/apply) which may provide parts -- possibly substantial parts -- of what you're trying to build.